# SQL Server: Using cursor to loop and insert incremental values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create this SQL Job, which is select from table (ot) and insert into another table (est_Request). ReqDocNo is a column in table est_Request which stored running numbers. As you can see in below code it will select max number from table est_Request and +1 to generate new one. Currently last number in the column is 0000068150. I need to do looping, because there will be thousands of records from table ot to insert into table est_Request.
But when I try to execute below query, the error show as '
'Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.est_Request' with unique index 'Request_ix1'. The duplicate key value is (0000068151, Sep 20 2019 12:00AM, Sep 20 2019 12:00AM).'

```
declare @ReqDocNo       nvarchar(10)

Declare reqdocno cursor for
select ReqDocNo from est_Request
open reqdocno
fetch next from reqdocno into @ReqDocNo

while @@fetch_status = 0
Begin

Select @ReqDocNo = isnull(max(ReqDocNo),0) + 1 from est_Request  
select @ReqDocNo  = right('0000000000' + convert(nvarchar(10),@ReqDocNo),10) 

insert  into est_Request
select @ReqDocNo,'',convert(date, pick_up_date, 103),convert(time,shift_time,103),convert(date,send_back_date,103),convert(time,send_back_time,103),pic,'',ext,convert(date, getdate()), convert(time,  getdate()),'','','','',status
FROM ot

fetch next from reqdocno into @ReqDocNo
end

close reqdocno
deallocate reqdocno
```

How can I achieve this?

Edit:
Index description for table est_Request:
PK_est_Request | nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY | ReqDocNo 
Request_ix1 | clustered, unique located on PRIMARY | ReqDocNo, PickUpDate, SendBackDate

Edit2:
I need to insert into another table too, so I tried using one of the solution given below:

```
    insert into est_RequestDetail
    Select ReqDocNo = right('0000000000'  
                    + convert(varchar(10), 
                              @ReqDocNo + row_number() over (order by ot.pick_up_date)), 
                     10), ot.empid, RouteNo,BusStopID,'',''  
      from est_BusGuest , ot
      where est_BusGuest.empid = ot.empid  
      and   routeNo in (select routeno from est_busroute a, est_buszone b  
                          where a.zoneno = b.zoneno  
                          and   b.branchid = '2')
```

Thanks all for helping me!

Comment: can you please share the schema for `est_Request` and `ot`?

Comment: you can achieve this using recursive query, rather than using cursors

Comment: Hi Squirrel, I don't know how to put schema here, so I just edit my post and put index description for table est_Request.

Comment: Don't do this to yourself. Just use an identity or a sequence. Any kind of roll your own identity like this is fraught with error. There are so many things that can cause this to go the wrong way. Things like concurrency and a whole list of other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cursor is not necessary here. A simple set base solution will do.

```
declare @ReqDocNo  int = 0;

-- first you get the max `ReqDocNo`. 
-- Assuming that the column only contains n umeric and no alpha
Select  @ReqDocNo = isnull(convert(int, max(ReqDocNo)), 0) 
from    est_Request;

-- while inserting into the table, use `row_number()` to generate a running number
insert  into est_Request ( {specify the column name here} )
select  ReqDocNo = right('0000000000' 
                        + convert(varchar(10), 
                                  @ReqDocNo + row_number() over (order by ot.pick_up_date)), 
                         10),
        {the rest of your convert query}
FROM    ot
```

Note :  you are getting the `duplicate key` error because you are inserting all rows from `ot` into `est_Request` with the same key value `@ReqDocNo`

Comment: Hi Squirrel, thank you very much for your answer and explanation. I did try, but I getting syntax error. Do I need to put bracket before right at Select ReqDocNo = right ?

Comment: Yeay it works! Thank u so much Squirrel! Another question, if I want to insert into another table too, I can use the same method? I mean, After insert into est_Request, I need to insert to another table(est_Detail), different columns, but still need ReqDocNo. Table est_Request.ReqDocNo = est_Detail.ReqDocNo

Answer (score 2):

Here's your script.

```
declare @max int
set @max = (select max(ReqDocNo) from est_Request);


with cte as (
    select  isnull(@max, 0) + 1 as ReqDocNo, 2 as ctr
    union all 
    select isnull(@max, 0) + ctr, ctr + 1 from  cte 
    where ctr <= @max

)
insert into est_Request 
(select right('0000000000' + convert(nvarchar(10), rn + ReqDocNo ), 10) 
    ,convert(date, pick_up_date, 103),convert(time,shift_time,103)
    ,convert(date,send_back_date,103),convert(time,send_back_time,103)
    ,pic,'',ext,convert(date, getdate()), convert(time,  getdate()),'','','','', [status] 
    from (
        select row_number() over (order by ReqDocNo) as rn, ReqDocNo from cte) t1 
    cross apply
        (select pick_up_date, shift_time, send_back_date,send_back_time,pic,ext,[status] 
            from ot) t2 
option (maxrecursion 0));
```

Comment: Hi Metal, thank you very much for your answer. I did try, but it returned error same as I put in my post.

Comment: its because of table ot

Comment: we need to generate the unique id with table `ot`. try this updated query