# SQL Server: SQL Job run once a day. If run more than once it will create error cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I has posted this question before: [SQL Server: Using cursor to loop and insert incremental values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024516/sql-server-using-cursor-to-loop-and-insert-incremental-values) (thanks for those who give me the solutions)

So I create the query as stored procedure and it will run daily. Here it is:

```
 CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_est_busrequest]
 As
 declare @ReqDocNo  int = 0;

 set nocount on

 Select  @ReqDocNo = isnull(convert(int, max(ReqDocNo)), 0) 
 from    est_Request;

 insert  into est_Request (ReqDocNo,Reason,PickUpDate,PickUpTime,SendBackDate,SendBackTime,Requester,DeptID,Ext,RequestDate,RequestTime,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate,Remark1,Remark2,Status )
 select  Distinct ReqDocNo = right('0000000000' 
                    + convert(varchar(10), 
                              @ReqDocNo + dense_rank() over (order by ot.pick_up_date, ot.shift_time)), 
                     10),
    '', pick_up_date ,shift_time , send_back_date, send_back_time ,pic,'',ext,convert(date, getdate()), convert(time, getdate()),'','','','',UPPER(status)
    FROM   ot

    insert into est_RequestDetail
    Select ReqDocNo = right('0000000000' 
                    + convert(varchar(10),  
                              @ReqDocNo + dense_rank() over (order by ot.pick_up_date, ot.shift_time)), 
                     10), ot.empid, RouteNo,BusStopID,'',''  
      from est_BusGuest , ot   
      where est_BusGuest.empid = ot.empid  
      and   routeNo in (select routeno from est_busroute a, est_buszone b  
                          where a.zoneno = b.zoneno  
                          and   b.branchid = '2') 

set nocount off

truncate table ot
```

table ot need to truncate because it will retrieve data from another system daily.

**table est_Request** and **est_RequestDetail** has index and primary key. Here is the info for index:

```
 Index description for table est_Request:  
 PK_est_Request | nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY | ReqDocNo 
 Request_ix1 | clustered, unique located on PRIMARY | ReqDocNo, PickUpDate, SendBackDate  

 Index description for table est_RequestDetail:  
 PK_est_RequestDetail | nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY | ReqDocNo, empID 
 Request_ix1 | clustered located on PRIMARY | ReqDocNo  
 Request_ix2 | nonclustered located on PRIMARY | ReqDocNo, empID
```

So if the SQL Job run one time per day, data will insert successfully and no error. However, I'm worried if there are need to run the SQL Job more than one in a day, maybe has error with data that require to manually trigger the job so it will create duplicate error. My question is, is this the right way to do, or do I need to change table structure like drop the index.

Comment: sorry, i didn't read your requirements completely

Comment: oh I see. it's okay :)

Comment: is there a way to identify that the rows in `ot` has been inserted into `est_Request` ? Or after insertion into `est_Request`, can you set an flag or indicator in `ot` table ?

Comment: @Squirrel, what I do is I remove set nocount off/on and then select from table est_RequestHeader to check if the rows has been inserted or not. If ReqDocNo column has increasing value so I assume the data has been inserted.

Comment: based on which columns ? is there a unique key column in `ot` that you can use to identify ? If you have that, you can simply use `insert into est_Request ... where not exists( ... )`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just understand your question. No unique key column in table `ot`.

Comment: how do you know that a row in `ot` is already inserted into the `est_Request` table ?

Comment: I also don't know how to know but what I did is I check by select data from est_Request and compare before and after I run the script. I couldn't set unique key in table `ot` as the data retrieved from different system, which I don't have access to it.

Comment: then how do you want to handle when the script is executed the second time ?

Comment: yeah...actually that's what I asked...I just think about it when DBA has do testing to execute the SQL Job this morning and error duplicate key has prompt..

Comment: how is records in table `ot` inserted ? will the same record insert twice in a day ?

Comment: Records into table `ot` will be insert from another system, by using SSIS. Actually the SQL Job will run only once per day, so no same record will be insert in a day. But my concern is what if some error happened and need to manually triggered the SQL Job again in the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script is fine, but you don't need to duplicate your `ReqDocNo` generation during insert of your main table and details table. here's what i would suggest, using cte as storage of your generated `ReqDocNo`

```
declare @ReqDocNoTb table(
        ReqDocNo varchar(50),
        EmpId int
);

with cte as (
    select  distinct ReqDocNo = right('0000000000' 
                    + convert(varchar(10), 
                              (select isnull(convert(int, max(ReqDocNo)), 0) from est_Request) + dense_rank() over (order by ot.pick_up_date, ot.shift_time)), 
                     10) as ReqDocNo,
                    EmpId    
    from ot
)
insert into @ReqDocNoTb(ReqDocNo, EmpId)
select ReqDocNo, EmpId from cte

--uncomment to check generated RecDocNo before inserting
--select * from @ReqDocNoTb 

insert into est_Request (ReqDocNo,Reason,PickUpDate,PickUpTime,SendBackDate,SendBackTime,Requester,DeptID,Ext,RequestDate,RequestTime,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate,Remark1,Remark2,Status)
select c.ReqDocNo,'', pick_up_date ,shift_time , send_back_date, send_back_time ,pic,'',ext,convert(date, getdate()), convert(time, getdate()),'','','','',UPPER(status) from @ReqDocNoTb c
    inner join ot o on o.EmpId = c.EmpId

insert into est_RequestDetail
select c.ReqDocNo, c.empid, b.RouteNo, b.BusStopID,'',''  
from est_BusGuest b, @ReqDocNoTb c   
      where est_BusGuest.empid = c.empid  
      and   routeNo in (select routeno from est_busroute a, est_buszone b  
                          where a.zoneno = b.zoneno  
                          and   b.branchid = '2')
```

Comment: I've got syntax error at with cte as(). is the bracket should close after insert into est_RequestDetail?

Comment: try now, added @ReqDocNoTb, to get generated RecDocNo, you can also try to select it first if you want to see the results, before inserting

Comment: I've got syntax error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.`  at  `10) as ReqDocNo,
                    EmpId    
    from ot
)`

Comment: i added semi colon after declare

Comment: I tried, but it returns duplicate key. I assume if there are need to run job again in a day, I would just delete data and manually triggered again the SQL Job. But anyway, thanks @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ for your help.